# The Input Type Search Didn't Show Up in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I make a file called SearchFields.Js

```
const SearchField = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <input 
      className="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300
      text-sm w-full indent-2 p-2.5 outline-none
      focus:border-blue-500 focus:ring-2 
      rounded-tl rounded-bl" 
      type="search" 
      placeholder="Search Anything Here .."
      />
      <button>Search</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default SearchField
```

And the Jumbotron.JS

```
  import React from 'react'

const Jumbotron = ({children}) => {
  return (
    <div className='bg-gray-900 flex items-center py-10'>
        <div className='max-w-md mx-auto w-full'>
            <h1 className='text-white text-center text-2xl font-bold
             mb-5'>Cari Gambar</h1>
             {children}
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Jumbotron
```

The Jumbotron comes up in the browser, but it didn't work for the SearchField.js
[image: the error]

There is supposed to be the input type search right below the "Cari Gambar". What's wrong in my code?

And another file is App.JS

```
import Jumbotron from "./components/Jumbotron";

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Jumbotron>
        
      </Jumbotron>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

It supposed to be like the image below:
[image: not error one]

Comment: Hey @aldo can yo share your code on https://codesandbox.io/ I will help you there. Thanks

Comment: I already make an account there, and put my code there. Now what I should do? https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-leftpad-6q5wvl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey i check your code on sandbox please update your App.js with following-

```
import Jumbotron from "./components/Jumbotron";
import Search from "./components/SearchField";

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Jumbotron>
        <Search/>
      </Jumbotron>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Hope you like the answer if you still facing issue lemme know.
Thanks

Comment: It works in this way, I just got confused when the tutorial on the youtube video doesn't pu "Search" between the Jumbotron inside App function but it works.